# Read latitude/longitude to create new point grid at higher resolution

Tags: postgresql, csv, latitude-longitude, numpy

New to SE, needed to reformat my other question. Basically I'm looking at reading a CSV with longitude and latitude points (in this case housing exposure, simplified below):

```
HUC4,Longitude,Latitude
1204,-95.956,30.05
1204,-95.955,30.048
```

And I would like to create a grid for each point in the form below. In my case I need to take the cell resolution (roughly 0.001) and increase this to around 30m or roughly 0.00025 decimal degrees.

```
newres = 0.00025
csvinput = open(file, 'r')
reader = csv.DictReader(csvinput, delimiter=',')

dst_file = open("out.csv",'wt')
dst_file.write( "longitude,latitude,huc4\n" )
lformat = '%.5f,%.5f,%5s'

for row in reader:
    huc4 = row['HUC4']
    # Longitude Value
    x = float(row["Longitude"])
    xup = x + newres
    xdwn = x - newres
    # Latitude values
    y = float(row["Latitude"])
    yup = y + newres
    ydwn = y - newres

xup  ,ydwn | xup, y  | xup , yup
x    ,ydwn |  x,  y  | x   , yup
xdwn ,ydwn | xdwn,y  | xdwn, yup
```

Then I just append each row to a new CSV. It's not very efficient.

I'm curious if there's an easier way to do this that doesn't involve raster creation and re-sampling. Ideally I would think that I can take the x/y values and create an array that I can just multiply by

```
longarray = [xup, x, xdwn, xup, x, xdwn, xup, x, xdwn]
latarray = [ydwn, ydwn, ydwn, y, y, y, yup, yup, yup]
```

Bottom line, I need to make sure that I am increasing the resolution of these points by a certain factor and I'm scared that if I create a grid out of the points and use GDAL, I will get some floating point errors later.

Any help / pointing me towards the right place?

Comment: Not sure if I've understood. Can you just take the bounding box of all your points and create a grid at your desired resolution?

Comment: I suggest not trying to calculate distances (i.e., make x by y cells) using latitude and longitude degrees - you'd be safer and more accurate to project those lat/long points to something like Texas State Plane (zone 4 for your area, I think). Then you can use feet or meters as Eastings and Northings, 15m in each cardinal direction. Also, you're not increasing resolution, you're defining areas around points, which of course have zero area on their own.

Comment: @alpha-beta-soup - So I believe I can do this but was apprehensive. Say I have the 100m grid (with many NA values) I can just convert lat long to array and multiply col by 3 and rows by 3, create an array and translate back to lat/long?

Comment: @PauloRaposo - I understand projected would probably be better, and you're correct about Texas, but I am trying to create a a uniform transformation across the entire country. Would you suggest translating into EPSG:5070/71? I just don't have much experience with trying to develop a country wide tool to increase the resolution of a grid by solely lat/long while outputting a flat file with long/lat so that I can input as exposure points...

Comment: @hydro_logic - I can't find EPSG:5070 on spatialreference.org, so I don't know what projection you're referring to. With respect to projections and coordinate systems across the country, you're gonna have to have some margin of error, nothing's perfect. Maybe Albers Equal Area Conic.
Am I understanding right that you want to make a 3x3 cell grid around each point?